# Return std::unique_ptr<T> from factory function creating fully hidden implementation of pure virtual interface

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, c++14

I was reading the [*Smart Pointer Programming Techniques*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html) provided in the boost documentation.

In the Section "[*using abstract classes for implementation hiding*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#abstract)", they provide a nice idiom to fully hide an implementation behind pure virtual interface. For example:

```
// Foo.hpp

#include <memory>

class Foo {
 public:
  virtual void Execute() const = 0;
 protected:
  ~Foo() = default;
};

std::shared_ptr<const Foo> MakeFoo();
```

and

```
// Foo.cpp

#include "Foo.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class FooImp final
    : public Foo {
public:
  FooImp()                         = default;
  FooImp(const FooImp&)            = delete;
  FooImp& operator=(const FooImp&) = delete;
  void Execute() const override {
    std::cout << "Foo::Execute()" << std::endl;
  }
};

std::shared_ptr<const Foo> MakeFoo() {
  return std::make_shared<const FooImp>();
}
```

Regarding the protected, non-virtual destructor in `class Foo`, the document states:

> Note the protected and nonvirtual destructor in the example above. The
>   client code cannot, and does not need to, delete a pointer to `X`; the
>   `shared_ptr<X>` instance returned from `createX` will correctly call
>   `~X_impl`.

which I believe I understand.

Now, it seems to me that this nice idiom could be used to produce a singleton-like entity if a factory function returned `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`; the user would be forced to `move` the pointer, with a compile-time guarantee that no copies exist.

But, alas, I cannot make the code work unless I change `~Foo() = default` from `protected` to `public`, and I do not understand why.

In other words, this does not work:

```
std::unique_ptr<const Foo> MakeUniqueFoo() {
    return std::make_unique<const FooImp>();
}
```

My questions:

1. Could you explain me why do I need to make `public` `~Foo() = default`?
2. Would it be dangerous to just remove `protected`?
3. Is the singleton-like idea even worth it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The issue has to do with how deleters work in smart pointers.

   In [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), the deleter is dynamic. When you have `std::make_shared<const FooImp>();`, the deleter in that object will call `~FooImpl()` directly:

   > The object is destroyed using delete-expression or a custom deleter that is supplied to shared_ptr **during construction**.

   That deleter will be copied onto the `shared_ptr<const Foo>` when it's created.

   In [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), the deleter is *part of the type*. It's:

   ```
   template<
       class T,
       class Deleter = std::default_delete<T>
   > class unique_ptr;
   ```

   So when you have `unique_ptr<const Foo>`, that will call `~Foo()` directly - which is impossible since `~Foo()` is `protected`. That's why when you make `Foo()` public, it works. Works, as in, compiles. You would have to make it `virtual` too - otherwise you'd have undefined behavior by only destructing the `Foo` part of `FooImpl`.
2. It's not dangerous. Unless you forget to make the destructor virtual, which, it bears repeating, will cause undefined behavior.
3. This isn't really singleton-like. As to whether or not it's worth it? Primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 3):

Every `shared_ptr` stores 4 things: a pointer, a strong reference count, a weak reference count, and a deleter.

The deleter gets the type from which the `shared_ptr` was constructed from, and deletes *that* type, not the exposed type.  If you cast it to a base `shared_ptr`, the derived deleter is still stored.

`unique_ptr` does not, by default, store such a stateful deleter.

The design reason behind this is that a `shared_ptr` is already managing extra resources: adding that deleter is cheap, given that you are already managing the reference counts.

For `unique_ptr`, without a stateful deleter, the overhead for it is basically identical to a raw pointer.  Adding a stateful deleter by default would make `unique_ptr`s significantly more expensive.

While they are both smart pointers, `unique_ptr` is really minimal, while `shared_ptr` is far more complex.

You can get around this by appending a stateful deleter to `unique_ptr`.

```
struct stateful_delete {
  void const* ptr = nullptr;
  void(*f)(void const*) = nullptr;
  template<class T>
  stateful_delete(T const* t):
    ptr(t),
    f([](void const* ptr){
      delete static_cast<T const*>(ptr);
    })
  {}
  template<class T>
  void operator()(T*)const{
    if (f) f(ptr);
  }
};

template<class T>
using unique_ptr_2 = std::unique_ptr<T, stateful_delete>;

template<class T>
unique_ptr_2<T> unique_wrap_2(T* t) {
  return {t, t};
}
template<class T, class...Args>
unique_ptr_2<T> make_unique_2(Args&&...args) {
  return unique_wrap( new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) );
}
```

such `unique_ptr_2` are 3 times as large as a `unique_ptr`.  They do not do an extra allocation (unlike `shared_ptr`).  And they will work with your non-virtual protected `~Foo` with a public `~FooImpl`.

You could reduce the size of `unique_ptr_2` down to 2 pointers if we use the `make_shared` technique of doing a unified allocation, and store the equivalent of the `ptr` and `f` on the heap.  I'm uncertain if that complexity is worth the savings.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Barry's answer an alternative to making it public is defining your own deleter which has access to your class' `~Foo()` method.

Example (tried with VS2013):

```
template <typename T>
class deleter
{
public:
    void operator()(T* a)
    {
        // Explicitly call the destructor on a.
        a->~A();
    }
};

class A {
    friend class deleter<A>; // Grant access to the deleter.
protected:
    ~A() {
        // Destructor.
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<A, deleter<A>> MakeA()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<A, deleter<A>>(new A());
}
```

Comment: This won't work in the OP's case, as the unique pointer actually holds a pointer to derived, and the above will delete the base.

Comment: Ofcourse, I missed the non-virtual base destructor.